# While plotting the graph using networkx and matplotlib, the weight for self-loop is not being diaplyed

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

Basically I want the weights of all my edges, including the self loop to be displayed.

```py
def graphTrial():

    G = nx.Graph()

    # Add nodes
    G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C'])

    # Add edges with weights
    G.add_edge('A', 'A', weight=5)
    G.add_edge('A', 'B', weight=2)
    G.add_edge('B', 'C', weight=3)

    # Define positions for nodes
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

    # Draw nodes and labels
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)

    # Draw edges with weights
    edge_labels = {(u, v): d['weight'] for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True)}
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)

    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Note, that the text object exists but is placed behind the node cause the interpolation does not take self loops into account.
To place it visibly, I adapted the networkx code from here [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_edge_labels). Here is the custom function.

```py
def draw_networkx_edge_labels(
    G,
    pos,
    edge_labels=None,
    label_pos=0.5,
    font_size=10,
    font_color="k",
    font_family="sans-serif",
    font_weight="normal",
    alpha=None,
    bbox=None,
    horizontalalignment="center",
    verticalalignment="center",
    ax=None,
    rotate=True,
    clip_on=True,
):
    """Draw edge labels.

    Parameters
    ----------
    G : graph
        A networkx graph

    pos : dictionary
        A dictionary with nodes as keys and positions as values.
        Positions should be sequences of length 2.

    edge_labels : dictionary (default=None)
        Edge labels in a dictionary of labels keyed by edge two-tuple.
        Only labels for the keys in the dictionary are drawn.

    label_pos : float (default=0.5)
        Position of edge label along edge (0=head, 0.5=center, 1=tail)

    font_size : int (default=10)
        Font size for text labels

    font_color : string (default='k' black)
        Font color string

    font_weight : string (default='normal')
        Font weight

    font_family : string (default='sans-serif')
        Font family

    alpha : float or None (default=None)
        The text transparency

    bbox : Matplotlib bbox, optional
        Specify text box properties (e.g. shape, color etc.) for edge labels.
        Default is {boxstyle='round', ec=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fc=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)}.

    horizontalalignment : string (default='center')
        Horizontal alignment {'center', 'right', 'left'}

    verticalalignment : string (default='center')
        Vertical alignment {'center', 'top', 'bottom', 'baseline', 'center_baseline'}

    ax : Matplotlib Axes object, optional
        Draw the graph in the specified Matplotlib axes.

    rotate : bool (default=True)
        Rotate edge labels to lie parallel to edges

    clip_on : bool (default=True)
        Turn on clipping of edge labels at axis boundaries

    Returns
    -------
    dict
        `dict` of labels keyed by edge

    Examples
    --------
    >>> G = nx.dodecahedral_graph()
    >>> edge_labels = nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G))

    Also see the NetworkX drawing examples at
    https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/auto_examples/index.html

    See Also
    --------
    draw
    draw_networkx
    draw_networkx_nodes
    draw_networkx_edges
    draw_networkx_labels
    """
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    if edge_labels is None:
        labels = {(u, v): d for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True)}
    else:
        labels = edge_labels
        # Informative exception for multiedges
        try:
            (u, v) = next(iter(labels))  # ensures no edge key provided
        except ValueError as err:
            raise nx.NetworkXError(
                "draw_networkx_edge_labels does not support multiedges."
            ) from err
        except StopIteration:
            pass

    text_items = {}
    for (n1, n2), label in labels.items():

        (x1, y1) = pos[n1]
        (x2, y2) = pos[n2]

        # no self-loop
        if n1 != n2:
            # this interpolates between pos[n1] and pos[n2] to place the label,
            # but just yields x1, y1 in case of self loops placing the label 
            # behind the node
            (x, y) = (
                x1 * label_pos + x2 * (1.0 - label_pos),
                y1 * label_pos + y2 * (1.0 - label_pos),
            )

        # self-loop; we find the loop coordinate to place the text
        else:
            # to identify the self-loop that corresponds to the node n1==n2
            loc = pos[n1]
            path_distance = np.zeros(len(ax.patches))
            for i, patch in enumerate(ax.patches):
                path = patch.get_path()
                loc = np.repeat(loc[None], len(path.vertices), axis=0)
                path_distance[i] = np.min(np.linalg.norm(loc - path.vertices, axis=1))
            patch = ax.patches[np.argmin(path_distance)]
            path = patch.get_path()
            x, y = path.vertices[int((0.5 - label_pos) * len(path.vertices))]

        if rotate:
            # in degrees
            angle = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) / (2.0 * np.pi) * 360
            # make label orientation "right-side-up"
            if angle > 90:
                angle -= 180
            if angle < -90:
                angle += 180
            # transform data coordinate angle to screen coordinate angle
            xy = np.array((x, y))
            trans_angle = ax.transData.transform_angles(
                np.array((angle,)), xy.reshape((1, 2))
            )[0]
        else:
            trans_angle = 0.0
        # use default box of white with white border
        if bbox is None:
            bbox = dict(boxstyle="round", ec=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), fc=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
        if not isinstance(label, str):
            label = str(label)  # this makes "1" and 1 labeled the same

        t = ax.text(
            x,
            y,
            label,
            size=font_size,
            color=font_color,
            family=font_family,
            weight=font_weight,
            alpha=alpha,
            horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment,
            verticalalignment=verticalalignment,
            rotation=trans_angle,
            transform=ax.transData,
            bbox=bbox,
            zorder=1,
            clip_on=clip_on,
        )
        text_items[(n1, n2)] = t

    ax.tick_params(
        axis="both",
        which="both",
        bottom=False,
        left=False,
        labelbottom=False,
        labelleft=False,
    )

    return text_items
```

Then your code yields the wanted output.

```py
G = nx.Graph()

# Add nodes
G.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

# Add edges with weights
G.add_edge('A', 'A', weight=5)
G.add_edge('A', 'B', weight=2)
G.add_edge('B', 'C', weight=3)
G.add_edge('C', 'C', weight=5)
G.add_edge('B', 'B', weight=2)
G.add_edge('D', 'A', weight=5)

# Define positions for nodes
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# Draw nodes and labels
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)

# Draw edges with weights
edge_labels = {(u, v): d['weight'] for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True)}
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
texts = draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, label_pos=0.5, rotate=True)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: graph with labeled self loops]